# Remove the similar Duplicates from list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, duplicates

I'm trying to remove the similar duplicates from my list.
Here is my code:

```
l = ["shirt", "shirt", "shirt len", "pant", "pant cotton", "len pant", "watch"]

res = [*set(l)]
print(res)
```

This will Remove only shirt word which is actually duplicate, but I'm looking to remove the similar words to remove like shirt Len,pant cotton,Len pant. Like that.

Expecting Output as
Shirt,pant,watch

Comment: What would be the definition of similar? Could you please elaborate on it, be specific

Comment: by similar do you mean if there is any substring that is present in the same list?

Comment: Similar means on my list you can see similar words like shirt Len,pant cotton. Like that. Or else.  Shirt as main word, shirt Len as duplicate. Like it. Idk you understand my pov are not

Comment: how is  `shirt len` similar to `pant cotton`?

Comment: No I'm not taking about substrings

Comment: In my list 3 times shirt word as repeated . 2times exact word "shirt" , 3rd time as shirt Len. So i need remove that 3rd time shirt word also. That i consider as similar

Comment: Is "shirt2" a duplicate of "shirt"?

Comment: Im expecting to achieve output as just Shirt,pant,watch . On my list

Comment: Yes shirt2 as duplicate and shirt Len which was 3rd as consider as similar one

Comment: is `shirt2` similar to `shirt len`?

Comment: Yes that's my pov. Shirt2 was similar to shirt Len.

Comment: why isnt shirt similar to pant? they have same letter `t`. what is the exact condition for similarity? Is the condition like if there is a substring of certain size that is common to both strings? if so what is that size?

Comment: Take a look at  the  `difflib` Module. It probably won't do what you want straightaway, but it may give you some idea of how you should go about defining clearly what you mean by _similar_.

Comment: Im considering similar what is , the word wise only, not single letter wise. I have 100 strings in list with shirt Len,shirt aha,shirt 2b. Like that i need to remove all that string which word have shirt. I guess it's total not possible. I will look for better solution myself. Thanks for help contribution

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to check if the single-word strings are in any other string, and if so remove them as a duplicate. I would go about it this way:

- Separate the list into single-word strings and any other string.
- For each longer string, check if any of the single-word strings is contained in it.

  - If so, remove it. Otherwise, add it to the result.
- Finally, add all the single-word strings to the result.

```py
l = ["shirt", "shirt", "shirt len", "pant", "pant cotton", "len pant", "watch"]

single, longer = set(), set()
for s in l:
    if len(s.split()) == 1:
        single.add(s)
    else:
        longer.add(s)

res = set()
for s in longer:
    if not any(word in s for word in single):
        res.add(s)
res |= single

print(res)
```

This example will give:

```
{'shirt', 'watch', 'pant'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

by selecting single word element from list and then apply set

```
lst = ["shirt", "shirt", "shirt len", "pant cotton", "len pant", "watch"]
set([ls for ls in lst if ' 'not in ls]) 
#Output {'pant', 'shirt', 'watch'}
```

note if your input will `["shirt", "shirt", "shirt len", "pant cotton", "len pant", "watch"]` then output will be `{'shirt', 'watch'}`

and if still would like to add `pant, cotton` then you can try

```
set(sum([ls.split(' ') for ls in lst], []))
#output {'cotton', 'len', 'pant', 'shirt', 'watch'}
```

and later filter out word by conditions as per your requirements

Comment: This might work with the current example, but I doubt it answers the requirements... Adding `"hello world"` to the list will remove it as well...

Comment: What you define the lst ?

Comment: hi @Hekna lst is your list (l).